# Git/Gerrit repository organisation for Eclipse plugins

Tags: git, eclipse-plugin, gerrit

We are developing a variety of eclipse plugins and currently host them on a central SVN server. Here we host a single project for each plug-in and can grant access to them on a per-developer basis.

We wish to migrate to the combination of GIT/Gerrit. But I can not make out a good way to keep the access controls while not making up to much repostorier. The only current solution I see is setting up a new Gerrit/Project for each plugin we currently use and grant access to them on per project basis.

This would mean that every developer has to manage several different GIT repositories in his workspace. And has the additional drawback, that it is impossible to commit changes to some corelated plug-ins together.

Is there any other solution I missed so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope you haven't missed much.  If you need different access controls, you have to have separate repositories.  There isn't a good way to tie changes across repositories together.  Some people at my office use git submodules with mixed levels of success, the rest of us just communicate in Gerrit that this change depends on that change.

Comment: I've seen a lot of teams where the granularity is in between. ex: 100 projects in 23 repos